# C Put 3 lines from textfile in 3 arrays

Tags: c, arrays, text-files

So I have a script that utilizes openalpr and writes 3 license plates to a text file.

The text file starts with a blank line, followed by 3 lines with 6 chars each

```
-imagine a newline here-
JV70BB
JV7OBB
JB7QBB
```

I want each license plate into an array, but I have some troubles finding out how to get each line into a seperate arary.

How would I go doing this?

```
if (ptr_file) {
while ((c = getc(ptr_file)) != EOF)
    //puts license plates into array here
fclose(ptr_file);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
int i, nb_plate = 3;
FILE *ptr_file = fopen("yourFile.txt", "r+");

char array[10][50]; //you can do malloc... don't forget to free
rewind(ptr_file); //rewind

while(cget(ptr_file) != '\r'); //skip 1st line
for(i=0;i<nb_plate;i++)
fscanf(ptr_file, "%s", &yourArray[i][0]); // get one plate
```

Comment: the '\r' will only work on a MAC for other OSs (and MAC) use '\n'.  Check the returned value from fscanf() to assure that a string conversion was successfully performed.  I think the format string should be " %s: so white space, like the newline is consumed

Answer (score 1):

Joining the license plate party.

`fgets()` is best for reading the line.  Code uses a scan set to validate the entries.

```
char buf[100];
// Validate empty line
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL || buf[0] != '\n') {
  Handle_Error();
}

#define LP_N (3)
char *lp[LP_N][7];
int i;
for (i = 0; i < LP_N; i++) {
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
    Handle_Error();
  }
  // Adjust per your license plate requirements
  static const char *format = "%6[0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]";
  if (sscanf(buf, format, &lp[i]) != 1 || strlen(lp) != 6) {
    Handle_Error();
  }
}
```

BTW: In OP's code, `c` should be `int c` to distinguish EOF from other `char`.

Comment: I got "int c" somewhere else in the code, but thanks for noticing. I couldn't get this to work properly, but I'll try! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the file character by character (which seems likely looking at your code), just make sure you read exactly 6 characters which you should put wherever you please, then read the newline character (either one or two, those can be any of '\r' and '\n'). You could use a simple while loop for that.

If you want to read it line by line, just read each line and save it in separate arrays, `fgets()` should do the job (or `fscanf()` with a correct format string).

Comment: _which you should put wherever you please_...  Do you really mean this?  :)

Comment: Well, I should add _'wherever you please as long as it is a sufficiently big char array'_ I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Use `fgets()` with a sufficiently long buffer, and copy over the buffer to each of the three arrays, depending on a modulus calculation on a loop counter:

```
#define MAX_LICENSE_PLATE_LENGTH 6

char license_plate_buffer[MAX_LICENSE_PLATE_LENGTH + 2] = {0};
char array_1[MAX_LICENSE_PLATE_LENGTH + 1] = {0};
char array_2[MAX_LICENSE_PLATE_LENGTH + 1] = {0};
char array_3[MAX_LICENSE_PLATE_LENGTH + 1] = {0};

unsigned int counter = 0U;

if (!ptr_file) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: No valid file pointer\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

while (fgets(license_plate_buffer, MAX_LICENSE_PLATE_LENGTH + 2, ptr_file) != NULL) {
    memcpy( (counter % 3 == 0) ? array_1 : ((counter % 3 == 1) ? array_2 : array_3), 
            license_plate_buffer, 
            MAX_LICENSE_PLATE_LENGTH);
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: fgets would also get the newline, so the buffer needs to  be 1 or 2 bytes longer than indicated above (depending on the OS) and the trailing newline needs to be overwritten with a '\0'

Comment: Per spec, `fgets()` will read up to six characters; unless the newline is needed, six bytes is all that is really needed, since the specification is known up front. Also, the intermediate buffer and three destination arrays are NULL-terminated when declared and initialized (see the `{0}` initialization). Since the `memcpy()` call only copies six bytes, the seventh remains the NULL terminator and so the arrays can be used downstream as strings, without any extra work.

Comment: @Alex `fgets(char *s, int n, FILE *stream)` will read up to 7 `char` given an `n` of 8.  All 7 could be non-`'\n'`.   Yet code does work as needed - just differ on a minor point of the comment "will read up to six characters; unless the newline is needed".

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `fgets()` in a loop to read the file.  It reads entire strings instead of characters:

```
FILE *fp = {0};
char buf[260];//arbitrarily big buffer
char strArray[3][7];//simple array, 3 string of 7 char each (enough for NULL terminator)
i = -1;
fp = fopen (path, "r");
if(fp)
{
    while (fgets (buf, 260, fp))//will continue to loop as long as there is a new line
    {
        if(strlen(buf) == 6)   {//check that string length matches that specified in your example code
            i++;                //anything bigger will overflow strArray[i], anything less is not a 
                                //valid license string (according to your current definitions)
            strcpy(strArray[i], buf);
        }   
    }
}
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: Should code instead use `if(strlen(buf) <= 6)`?  `<=` vs `>=` or maybe `if(strlen(buf) < sizeof strArray[i])`

Comment: needs to add a definition for 'buf' like char buf[200];  I think fgets() will include the newline, so the buf needs to be truncated by buf[strlen(buf) = '\0';

Comment: @user3629249 `buf[strlen(buf)] = '\0'` does nothing useful: setting the null character to the null character.  `buf[strlen(buf)-1] = '\0'` is a problem in exceptional cases.  Suggest instead `size_ t len = streln(buf); if (len > 0 && buf[len-1] == '\n') buf[--len] = 0;`  [Trimming fgets](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/67608/trimming-fgets-strlen-or-strtok)

Comment: @chux - Yeah,  I originally choose to use `>= 6` because of strict definition of strings being read in.   Upper limit is guaranteed by 2nd argument in `fgets()`.  Just changed it to be `==` to match specific definition in OP.   But in general I agree, typically I do more to qualify raw input from a file before processing.  This was just a concept offering to point out use of `fgets()` rather than `getc()`.  Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
much better to use fgets() to read each line of the file

if (ptr_file) 
{
    char licensePlate[10];

    memset( licensePlate, 0x00, sizeof( licensePlate ) );
    if( NULL == fgets( licensePlate, sizeof(licensePlate), ptr_file )
    {
        perror( "fgets failed on first line" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fgets successful

    // this was the leading blank line, do, do nothing

    // get first plate
    memset( licensePlate, 0x00, sizeof( licensePlate ) );   
    if( NULL == fgets( licensePlate, sizeof(licensePlate), ptr_file )
    {
        perror( "fgets failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fgets successful

    if( '\n' == licensePlate[ strlen(licensePlate) )
    {
        licensePlate[ strlen(licensePlate)] = '\0'; // chop off trailing newline
    }
    strcpy( plateArray_1, licensePlate );

    // get second plate
    memset( licensePlate, 0x00, sizeof( licensePlate ) );   
    if( NULL == fgets( licensePlate, sizeof(licensePlate), ptr_file )
    {
        perror( "fgets failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fgets successful

    if( '\n' == licensePlate[ strlen(licensePlate) )
    {
        licensePlate[ strlen(licensePlate)] = '\0'; // chop off trailing newline
    }
    strcpy( plateArray_2, licensePlate );

    // get third plate
    memset( licensePlate, 0x00, sizeof( licensePlate ) );   
    if( NULL == fgets( licensePlate, sizeof(licensePlate), ptr_file )
    {
        perror( "fgets failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fgets successful

    if( '\n' == licensePlate[ strlen(licensePlate) )
    {
        licensePlate[ strlen(licensePlate)] = '\0'; // chop off trailing newline
    }
    strcpy( plateArray_3, licensePlate ); 



    fclose(ptr_file);

However, if there were more plates to read, I would make 
the code from memset to strcpy into a sub routine 
and pass in the ptr_file and address of the receiving array
```

Comment: While probably correct, this does a lot of unnecessary work, given the specification for license plates is known ahead of time. We don't need to copy the newline character, and we can initialize NULL-terminated arrays to copy bytes over to.

Comment: `if( '\n' == licensePlate[ strlen(licensePlate) ]` is never true.